# RMI Client Authentication in Spring Remoting

Tags: java, spring

How do we authenticate a client invoking a remote method in spring remoting via RMI. There are a lot of examples for authentication when other methods such as HTTP invoker, Hessian,web services for remoting are used but cant seem to find any for remoting via RMI.

To give you a simple scenario, a rmi server is running on one machine, and a client accesses it from another machine using rmi. All this is done using the spring remoting packages.
So I want to be able to authenticate the client , for example i would want the server to authenticate and serve all requests coming in from clients on machine A,B,C but reject client requests from other machines.

Any Suggestions ?

Regards,

Comment: You are probably going to need a custom implementation of the `RemoteInvocationFactory` and a custom `RemoteInvocation`. You might want to checkout the Spring Security implementation for some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look and get back.

Comment: I am also looking for an answer on this

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you should use RMI with SSL certificates
For more information visit: 
http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~akonstan/rmi-ssl/

Comment: but is this pluggable into spring remoting ?

Comment: @sigi Doesn't help much. How do you do it with spring remoting?